# I did zoom in/out of image in a pictureBox but how do i avoid from the image to become distorted ?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top of form1 I did:

```
double increment = 25;
```

Then:

```
void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Focus();
        }

        void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            double factor = 1.0;
            if (e.Delta > 0)
                factor += (increment / 100.0);
            else
                factor -= (increment / 100.0);
            pictureBox1.Image = resizeImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Size((int)(pictureBox1.Image.Width * factor), (int)(pictureBox1.Image.Height * factor)));

        }

        public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }
```

Its working but there two problems:

1. If you increase the size by 25%, then decrease by 25%, you won't get back the size that you started with. For example, 100 + 25% = 125, 125 -25% = 94 (because 25% of 100 is 25, but 25% of 125 is 31).    By how ot increase/decrease it ? And how do I limit it as minimum and maximum size ?
2. If I will continually increase and decrease the size, sooner or later the picture will become distorted. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace addition / subtraction with multiplication / division (1 * 1.25 = 1.25, 1.25 / 1.25 = 1) e.g.:

  ```
  double increment = 1.25;   
  double factor = 1.0;
  if (e.Delta >  0)
      factor *= increment;
  else
      factor /= increment;
  ```
- The problem is that you are generating a new version of an image based on a previously generated, not the original one. If you decrease the resolution of some picture, you are losing some information. It is a one way process. In other words you cannot decrease an image and then increase it and expect that the result will be the same as the original one. I think that you should always pass the original image to the resizeImage method. The original image can be stored in a field or can be read every time from resources or from a file.
- Before assigning a new image to *pictureBox1.Image* you should dispose the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider displaying a different, bigger version of the image on mouseover, rather than the same image enlarged.